# ???? вместо русских символов

Tags: c++

Простейший код, выводит "?????". В чём проблема? Такая же фигня с некоторыми програми на компе, в чём проблема и как исправить?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
cout <<"Дароу"<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Так покажите этот код. / Какой язык установлен в системе для неюникодных программ?

Comment: код добавил в шапку.

Comment: какой, простите, язык??

Comment: Control Panel > Region > Administrative > Language for non-Unicode programs. [тыц](https://c.mql5.com/3/179/2018-03-11_22h37_29.png)

Comment: Файл конвертнули в UTF-8 без BOM? Похоже, что нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Control Panel > Region > Administrative > Language for non-Unicode program и меняем на русский

вариант на русской винде:

> Панель управления > Часы, язык и регион > Региональные стандарты (Регион) > Дополнительно > Изменить язык системы..  и меняем на русский

Перезагрузка..

Вот это мне помогло, всем спасибо за ответы.

Comment: На правах нытья... Все, кто использует неюникодные кодировки в своих программах, должны быть отлучены от разработки.

Comment: Я вас не понял.

Comment: Всегда и везде используйте юникод. В частности, `wstring`, `wchar`, `wcout`, `wcin`. Потому что в противном случае ваши программы будут правильно отображаться только на тех машинах, где язык системы соответствует вашему. На других будут кракозябры.

Comment: это аналоги string, char, cout ,cin?

Comment: Да. `w` - от `wide` - широкий символ. Грубо говоря, юникод.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй в свойствах консоли выставить Lucida Console

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ответил выше, проблема была не в этом